# 504 Gateway Timeout when Creating Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Since yesterday, [Team Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta) endpoint fails with 2 distinct behaviours:

- Sometimes, it returns a `504 Gateway Timeout`, but it seems like the Team is created anyway
- Other times, it returns a `202` but when redirected to the `/operations` URI, the operation remains in a `notStarted` state. In this case, it also seems like the Team was created.

Also filed in Github: [Issue #7890](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7890)

Comment: Are you still facing this issue ?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Yes, still having the same issue today.
Receiving a 504 with the following body in the response: `{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "4e2f2032-ad90-427c-ad46-8e3795c97fdc",
      "date": "2020-04-24T17:13:17"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Are you operating the service form Europe region?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT no, from East NA, here are the diagnostics form the server received in a error response header: `{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Canada East","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_8"}}`

Comment: @odruin, We are discussing this issue with internal team, will get back to your once we receive any update

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT The issue does not occur anymore on my end and the endpoint now seems to work normally.

Comment: Thanks for your update. If you face this issue in future, please post here.